# Test for displaying button only when conditions are true

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I have a render function as shown below:

```
private render(): JSX.Element {
  return ( 
    <div>
      {this.props.x && this.state.y &&
        <DefaultButton onClick = { this.onDeleteButtonClick } >
          Delete
        </DefaultButton>
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Only when the 2 conditions `this.props.x` and `this.state.y` are true, then display the button.

Similarly,

```
class TitleContainer extends React.Component {
  private isPageEnabled: boolean = false;
  private isSubmitter: boolean = false;
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.isPageEnabled && this.isSubmitter &&
          <div>
            <br />
            <SubmitAppFormContainer />
          </div>
        }    
      </div>
    );
   }
 }
```

Only when the 2 conditions `this.isPageEnabled` && `this.isSubmitter` are true, then display `SubmitAppFormContainer`.

How do I write a test for the same? Please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you know how to write tests in general. The tricky part here is to write classes, that are easily testable. In your first case it could be simple:

```
it('shows DefaultButton', () => {
    const shallowRenderer = new ShallowRenderer();
    shallowRenderer.render(<Component
        x={true}
    />);
    const result = shallowRenderer.getRenderOutput();
    expect(result).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Create 2 tests, one time passing `x = true`, the other one passing `x = false`, so you test both cases. You just have to somehow set the `y`-state to true.

In your second case `TitleContainer` it seems more complicated. How can the values of `isPageEnabled` and `isSubmitter` be modified? If it's not possible from the outside, it can not be tested properly. Use props if possible.